# YoloV8 Instance Segmentation Model Deployment to Roboflow Error: InvalidDatasetException Dataset is not of the correct type

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation, yolo, roboflow

I am using YOLOV8 for instance segmentation using Google Colab. Now, after I **download, train, validate, and test my dataset from Roboflow**, I want to upload my model/weights to a specific project version to use it as my API. I follow their [documentation](https://blog.roboflow.com/upload-model-weights-yolov8/) upon deploying it, but I got an error due to the method is only for object detection type. I would really appreciate your attention.

[This is my code looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQQBD.png)

and this is what it looks like when I open the link.
[message upon clicking the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1lbM.png)

Code Snippet: `project.version(2).deploy(model_type="yolov8", model_path=f"/content/drive/MyDrive/PATH/model/runs/segment/train4/")`

Error Snippet: `{ "message": "Dataset is not of the correct type.", "type": "InvalidDatasetException", "hint": "This method can only be used on object detection datasets." }`

I already applied the methods in the following articles but still I got the same error.
https://roboflow.com/deploy
https://docs.roboflow.com/upload-weights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model weights uploads are only available for object detection models from YOLOv8 at this time. I've just made an update to the blog post to make it a bit more clear.

I do want to add that it was already added to the documentation when the feature was released.

- https://docs.roboflow.com/upload-weights#upload-yolov8-model-weights
  [image]

Comment: I see, thank you for this. What alternative do you reccomend for this?

Comment: We’re working on adding it. If you want to get on the wait list & potentially early access when it’s ready please reach out (either via our forum or sales form depending on whether it’s for a personal or business project).